# Scala group by mapping keys

Tags: scala

Say I have a map like this:

```
val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d", ...)
```

Say I have a function: `def f(i: Int): String` that I want to apply to the keys of this map. I then want to group by the resulting f(key) and concatenate all the strings (values) belonging to the same f(key) group.

Is there an efficient way to "groupByKey" while mapping the key in plain scala (no spark).

Comment: Your sample data m is all different keys. What do you want to group there? Does f(i) return the same result for some of the (i: Int), and you like to group on that result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the situation, you have a Map...

```
val m: Map[K,V] = ...
```

...and a function/method that transforms the keys...

```
def f(k: K):J = ...  //K and J can be same type
```

...and you want to group the keys from the `Map` and then collect all the values from the `Map` into their new groups.

```
m.keys                 //Iterable[K]
 .toList               //List[K]
 .groupBy(f)           //Map[J,List[K]]
 .mapValues(_.map(m))  //Map[J,List[V]]
```

If your original `V` is itself a `List` then you could `flatMap()`, instead of `map()`, to flatten the results.

The `toList` step is optional. Without it the result is `Map[J,Iterable[V]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because both 1 and 3 got mapped to 'odd' and Map must enforce uniqueness of the keys, one pair will be dropped. A simple solution is convert the original Map[Int, String] to Seq[Int, String] that does not enforce uniqueness. For example:

```
m.toSeq.map {
case (k, v) => (if (k % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd", v)
}.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(
  values => values.map(_._2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `foldLeft` to do this:

```
val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d")
m: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d)

m.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, String]) {
    case (accum, (i, s)) if i % 2 == 0 => accum + ("even" -> accum.get("even").fold(s)(existing => existing + s))
    case (accum, (i, s)) => accum + ("odd" -> accum.get("odd").fold(s)(existing => existing + s))
}

//scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(odd -> ac, even -> bd)
```

Edit:

> I have lots of cases instead of just "even" and "odd". What if I wanted to modulo on 1000, so there are 1000 different groups. I can't enumerate them all as cases in the foldLeft function. Is there a more generic way to do this?

To generalize this we need to just use a better key than "even" or "odd". In this case, it sounds like the key would be based on `i` in this. So let's just use module 10 as an example to avoid large console print outs. Let's make a new map with a bunch of stuff:

```
import scala.util.Random
val testMap = (0 to 30).map(i => i -> Random.alphanumeric.filter(_.isLetter).take(Random.nextInt(3)).mkString("")).toMap
```

This can make us a sample map with some random letters in each place for each of our entries.

And then its actually only once case since our keying function is now just `i` itself module 10.

```
testMap.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, String]) {
    case (accum, (i, s)) => accum + (i % 10 -> accum.get(i % 10).fold(s)(existing => existing + s))
}
```

Or, to make things a little more obvious:

```
testMap.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, String]) {
    case (accum, (i, s)) => {
        val key = i % 10
        accum + (key -> accum.get(key).fold(s)(existing => existing + s))
    }
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
testMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> q, 5 -> Ax, 10 -> a, 24 -> AX, 25 -> "", 14 -> U, 20 -> "", 29 -> R, 1 -> hB, 6 -> ky, 28 -> ch, 21 -> dk, 9 -> v, 13 -> BR, 2 -> R, 17 -> "", 22 -> h, 27 -> "", 12 -> "", 7 -> "", 3 -> "", 18 -> "", 16 -> Qu, 11 -> XO, 26 -> gS, 23 -> "", 8 -> "", 30 -> fn, 19 -> "", 4 -> "", 15 -> Br)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> fn, 5 -> Br, 1 -> XO, 6 -> gS, 9 -> "", 2 -> "", 7 -> "", 3 -> "", 8 -> "", 4 -> U)

scala> testMap.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, String]) {
     | case (accum, (i, s)) => accum + (i % 10 -> accum.get(i % 10).fold(s)(existing => existing + s))
     | }
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> qafn, 5 -> AxBr, 1 -> hBdkXO, 6 -> kyQugS, 9 -> Rv, 2 -> Rh, 7 -> "", 3 -> BR, 8 -> ch, 4 -> AXU)
```

Comment: this is ok for my question, but in practice, I have lots of cases instead of just "even" and "odd". What if I wanted to modulo on 1000, so there are 1000 different groups. I can't enumerate them all as cases in the foldLeft function. Is there a more generic way to do this?

Comment: @user3685285 I've updated the answer with generalized fold

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your changed requirement correctly, you're trying to concatenate all the values of a Map whose keys are divisible by a given integer?  If so, here's one approach:

```
val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d", 5 -> "e", 6 -> "f", 7 -> "g")

def f(m: Map[Int, String], n: Int): String =
  m.filter{
    case (k, v) => k % n == 0
  }.toSeq.map{
    case (k, v) => (n, v)
  }.groupBy(_._1).
  mapValues(_.map(_._2).mkString).
  getOrElse(n, "")

f(m, 3)
// res1: String = fc
```

Comment: @user3685285, it looks like your original requirement has been significantly changed.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, let's assume f is something, which leads to same f(i) for different i:

```
def f(i: Int) : String = if (i % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd" 
f: (i: Int)String
```

so that we have something to group.

```
val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d")
```

Mapping:

```
m.map {case (k,v) => ((k, (f(k), v)))}
res82: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,(String, String)] = Map(1 -> (odd,a), 2 -> (even,b), 3 -> (odd,c), 4 -> (even,d))
```

Grouping:

```
scala> m.map {case (k,v) => ((k, (f(k), v)))}.groupBy {case (k,(fs, v)) => fs} 
res83: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,(String, String)]] = Map(odd -> Map(1 -> (odd,a), 3 -> (odd,c)), even -> Map(2 -> (even,b), 4 -> (even,d)))
```

A function, to pull out the Strings from the map and concatenate them:

```
scala> def myconcat (m: Map [Int, (String, String)]) : String = m.values.foldLeft ("") {(z, s2) => z + s2._2}
myconcat: (m: Map[Int,(String, String)])String
```

Combined with the above mapping and grouping:

```
scala> m.map {case (k,v) => ((k, (f(k), v)))}.groupBy  {case (k,(fs, v)) => fs}.map (fsv => myconcat (fsv._2)) 
res90: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(ac, bd)
```

Pretty complex. :)